# Initialise a reference member to C array don't compile on visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

When I try to compile the code below on g++ it's work but on vs2015 it's fail with message :
error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const bool *' to 'const bool (&)[3]'

```
#include <iostream>

enum class Direction
{
       RIGTH,
       LEFT
};

struct Buffer
{
       int catRigth = 4;
       int catLeft = 8;
       bool dogRigth[3] = {true, false, true};
       bool dogLeft[3] = {false, true, false};
};

struct Bind
{
       const int &cat;
       const bool (&dog)[3];
       Bind(const Buffer &buf, Direction direction) :
              cat(direction == Direction::RIGTH ? buf.catRigth : buf.catLeft),
              dog(direction == Direction::RIGTH ? buf.dogRigth : buf.dogLeft)
       {
       }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

       const Buffer buff;

       Bind bindRigth(buff, Direction::RIGTH);
       Bind bindLeft(buff, Direction::LEFT);

       int catRigth = bindRigth.cat;
       int catLeft = bindLeft.cat;

       std::cout << catRigth << " " << catLeft;
}
```

Is it a standard C++ code or it's gcc specific comportment?

Comment: Or in other words: does the conditional operator trigger array-to-pointer decay?

Comment: Seems like only MSVC has this behavior. clang, gcc and icc work as "expected"

Comment: Initialize it like this: _dog { direction == Direction::RIGTH ? buf.dogRigth : buf.dogLeft)} {}

Comment: Tried your code out on cpp.sh, it complained about obj not being initialized. Did that, worked then. Maybe doing that makes it work on vs2015 too? (Altered code: http://cpp.sh/3wqyg ) In any case ugly code, why don't you simply use a pointer?

Comment: Sorry I accepted the edit by Felix when I probably don't do, I'm new here. I tested my code on real vs and it don't  compiled.

Comment: By the way, you're spelling "right" wrong.

Comment: @Aziuth It's not ugly, it's simplified. Shame that I made a mistake though. But you really should have tried MSVC yourself instead of writing a misleading comment.

Comment: @felix Thing is, you need to know that this is a reference to an array to be able to read the code. And the syntax is anything but intuitive, I'd say. Imagine you have somebody who reads that code without further explanations and never saw this very syntax, but is otherwise not a beginner. Do you think he easily understands it? I'd consider using a pointer to be far more readable.

Comment: @Aziuth Yes, one certainly need to learn a programming language in order to read the code which is written in that programming language. But you miss the whole point of this question. He is simply confused by the behavior of a non conformant compiler. For those he who don't understand ref to array, I would encourage him to try a little harder, since he already managed in understanding how pointer works (if he really did).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSVC shouldn't have decayed its type to `const bool *`:

> 5.16.4 If the second and third operands are glvalues of the same value category and have the same type, the result is of that type and value category and it is a bit-field if the second or the third operand is a bit-field, or if both are bit-fields.

A workaround for MSVC could be:

```
#include <utility>

const struct A {
    bool a[3] = {false};
} obj;

template <class Lhs, class Rhs>
auto &&Conditional(const bool x, Lhs &&lhs, Rhs &&rhs) {
    if (x)
        return std::forward<Lhs>(lhs);
    return std::forward<Rhs>(rhs);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const bool (&t)[3] = Conditional(true, obj.a, obj.a);
    return 0;
}
```

PS: Conditional isn't a constexpr function.

Or: `const bool (&t)[3] = *(true ? &obj.a : &obj.a);`

Comment: Thanks your solution to reference on ternary and dereference the result do the job for me